# VB.net Change Variable To another locations but keep folder path

Tags: vb.net, variables, directory

Hey guys I think I'm making this a lot more difficult that it should, but I am unable to resolve it.

I have a variable ConvertDir which the user can select (but for this purpose say it is C:\test), and they select a Save Dir (C:\testApp).

It will search in the ConvertDir for files, it records the location where the file was found and records it(say it is C:\test\A\1\Test), then I want it to make it copy to the same folder structure but on the SaveDir (So C:\testApp\A\1\Test) there are loads of other files and folders.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the code you have written so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do a `string.replace`, then? 
Something looking like:

```
File.Copy(SelectedFilePath, SelectedFilePath.Replace(ConvertDir,SaveDir))
```

Also, just look at the example provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx) for some ideas about how to do this as a whole.

Hope this helps...